# EF one to many relation

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many

I use EF's code first approach. I have the following three classes:

```
public class Inquiry
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Contractor Contractor { get; set; }
    public IList<ApplicationUser> InquiryUsers { get; set; }
    public IList<InquiryComment> Comments { get; set; }
    public IList<HydroTechEmail> Emails { get; set; } 
    public InquiryState State { get; set; }
    public List<string> Attachments { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? TimeOfCreation { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeOfModification { get; set; }
}

public class HydroTechEmail    
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string FromDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string FromAddress { get; set; }
    public List<string> ToDisplayName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ToAddress { get; set; }
    public HydroTechEmailState State { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReceivedTime { get; set; }
    public virtual List<HydroTechEmailAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Firstname {get;set;}
    public string Lastname {get;set;}
}
```

I thought EF will generate some intermediate classes for relation Inquiry -> Many Emails and Inquiry -> Many Application Users. Instead it created a foreign keys in ApplicationUser and HydroTechEmail classes to Inquiry class. How should I create this one to many relations? 
The strange is that for Comments it created an intermediate table named InquiryComments.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework will only generate intermediate tables for many-to-many relationships.

For one-to-many relationships, no intermediate tables will be created because it is not necessary.

Comment: but it does not make sense...one inquiry might have many users but I don't have Inquiry_Users table in a database. Instead I have foreign key in Users table (Fk_Inquiry_Id) to reference inquiry. So this is not correct, because in that case it might be only one-to-one relation.

Comment: The solution was to add property Inquiries to both ApplicationUser and HydroTechEmail classes and decorate them with [InverseProperty("SpecificProperty_In_Inquiry_Class") attribute

Comment: Glad to know you already found the answer. If a collection property (eg IList<>) only exists on one of the classes, EF will treat this as a one-to-many relationship. Collection properties need to be present in both entities for EF to determine that what you want is a many-to-many relationship.